# Ruby find and replace string

Tags: ruby

Can anyone help me to find and replace the string

```
if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
}
if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
    cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
}
```

in the above string I need to find

```
cdvVersionCode = null
```

and replace as below

```
cdvVersionCode = 300
```

Comment: This is not ruby code, also entirely lacks context and specification I have no idea how an answer was even provided in this case.

Comment: @engineersmnky This not a ruby code of course, this is the string to be replaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby , the `[]=` method is also known as [slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D). Here is an example:

```
str = "qwertyuiop"
str["rty"] = "zxc"
p str # => "qwezxcuiop"
```

Comment: Somehow I don't think the question actually pertains to string substitution. It needs clarification.

Comment: @steenslag Thanks for your fast reply, it's working good